# My First Riddle - What am I?

Tags: riddle

Amber, leather, fruit, or pine. Whiskey, crackers, never wine.

White and red across a sea. Or clad twice in sable, burgundy.

Hidden, swung, hooked, flown. Suited, bottled, jumping, thrown.

You'll never get me if you're slow. Who I am? Well, "You don't know..."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This could be

> JACK or JACKS

Because

> It seems most of these words can be combined with the word JACK to have a greater meaning
>  Amber - Amberjack is an Atlantic and Pacific fish
>  leather - Leather Jacket? *EDit - @Stiv suggests Leatherjacket Fish or Leather Jack
>  fruit -  Jackfruit
>  pine - Jack pine , pine tree
>  Whiskey - Jack Daniels
>  crackers - Cracker Jack
>  never wine - No Jack Wine?
>  White and red across a sea - Union Jack, flag of UK
>  Or clad twice in sable, burgundy - Dunno, Jack Black twice in Anchorman?
>  Hidden, swung, hooked, flown -  A JACK is a flag flown from a short jackstaff at the bow (front) of a vessel
>  
>  Suited - Jacks are trump in Eucker
>  bottled - Bottle of Jack, Jack Daniels
>  jumping - Jumping Jacks
>  thrown - Throwing Jacks
>  You'll never get me if you're slow - Jack be nimble and quick
>  Who I am? Well, "You don't know..." - You Don't Know Jack, old computer game I used to play :) - This one really solidified it for me.

Comment: Well done!  I'd love to know which ones you got/didn't and if you have any suggestions for improvement.

Comment: Finding the line between giving too many clues and making a puzzle too difficult is tough. This has quite a few clues but most are knowledge based. I would say it falls into the GOOD category. Nice Job!

Comment: Nice spot :) I think #2 is similar to your #1, i.e. [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leatherjacket_fish) and the 'never wine' strikes me as just something you *cannot* attach it to, in contrast to the two that go before it... (maybe?)